# feval error nlfilter, reference to a cleared variable

Tags: matlab

Here is a part of a function I am trying for testing a larger function.

```
function funct(subfn)
clear all; % this is now removed
clc;
I = rand(11,11);
ld = input('Enter the lag = ') % prompt for lag distance
A = nlfilter(I, [7 7], str2func(subfn));


% Subfunction
    function [h] = dirvar(I)
        c = (size(I)+1)/2
        EW = I(c(1),c(2):end)
        h = length(EW) - ld
    end

% Subfunction
    function [h] = diagvar(I)
        c = (size(I)+1)/2
        NE = diag(I(c(1):-1:1,c(2):end))
        h = length(NE) - ld
    end
end
```

If I remove the `clear all` statement, then the following error appears,

```
Enter the lag = 1

ld =

     1

??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or method 'dirvar' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> nlfilter at 61
b = mkconstarray(class(feval(fun,aa(1+rows,1+cols),params{:})), 0, size(a));

Error in ==> funct at 5
A = nlfilter(I, [7 7], str2func(subfn));
```

Please **ignore** this part as I have now removed `clear all` statement as suggested in an answer below.
When I run `funct('dirvar')` I am greeted with this error:

```
Enter the lag = 1

ld =

     1

??? Reference to a cleared variable subfn.

Error in ==> funct at 6
A = nlfilter(I, [7 7], str2func(subfn));
```

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT (i.e. never) put `clear all` inside a function. `subfn` is defined as the function is called, clear all removes this definition. Remember that a function has its own workspace, which is different from the base workspace seen by the command line. Thus, all that `clear all` can do for you is make a mess.

**EDIT**

Since [STR2FUNC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html) doesn't allow you to construct function handles from nested functions, you may want to use a `switch/case` block to select your function, i.e.

```
function funct(subfn)

%# construct the right handle
switch subfn
case 'dirvar'
   subfn = @dirvar;
case 'diagvar'
   subfn = @diagvar;
otherwise
   error('subfunction %s not defined',subfn)
end

I = rand(11,11);
ld = input('Enter the lag = ') % prompt for lag distance
A = nlfilter(I, [7 7], subfn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your clear all statement clears the input parameter to the function, 'subfn'.  This is the expected behavior.

According to the [str2func docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html), "Nested functions are not accessible to str2func. To construct a function handle for a nested function, you must use the function handle constructor, @."